# Vim Pattern replace

Tags: regex, vim

```
 <created>
  pat@c.com 
</created>
```

I want to replace the above with but the username may vary i.e,pat@c.com ,harry@c.com...

```
  <created>
   tom@c.com
  </created>
```

What is the command to replace this in vim

```
 %s/<created>\r*\r</created>/new string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me like this:

```
%s/<created>\n\s*\w*@\w*\n<\/created>/newstring/
```

If you wanted to re-insert the e-mail address you can use:

```
%s/<created>\n\s*\(\w*@\w*\)\n<\/created>/newstring: \1/
```

A bit of explanation:

- `\n`: newline
- `\s`: spaces and tabs
- `\w`: any word character
- `\(` and `\)`: capture what's inside
- `\1`: use the first captured expression

Comment: Try using a different delimiter for clarity, since you have "/" in your pattern: "%s#<created>\n\s*\w*@\w*\n</created>#newstring#".

Comment: Thanks guys,This is the first time i got a reply for a vim editor question.

Comment: Can u explain the above.Not working for me now..

Comment: @Hulk, updated my answer, how is not working?

Comment: It is now.......